# Setting description of an item in Visual Studio -and- changing what "this" refers to

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, attributes, tooltip, statusstrip

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 and I'm dealing with C#; I've made a `statusStrip` that I intend to use as my tool-tip viewer, its `.text` attribute changing depending on the control the mouse has entered. I've got two `textBoxes` and I'm trying to make it such that entering the control fires a function called `tooltipEnter`, and leaving it fires a function called `tooltipLeave`. Here's my code for those two functions:

```
    private void tooltipEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = this.AccessibleDescription;
    }

    private void tooltipLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Look here for tool-tips regarding the form!";
    }
```

The problem with this is that, **first**, I'm not sure `AccessibleDescription` is the right attribute to saddle the description to, and I'm not sure of the most elegant way to do the `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text` assignment in the first place. **Second**, `this` in the program's frame of reference refers to the form on which these controls lay, not the controls themselves; How do I refer uniformly to "the control that just got entered" in a way that allows me to have just the one function for all entries, without having to make different ones for each control?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem with this is that, first, I'm not sure
>   AccessibleDescription is the right attribute to saddle the description
>   to, and I'm not sure of the most elegant way to do the
>   toolStripStatusLabel1.Text assignment in the first place.

`AccessibleDescription` is just some string instance referenced in your form, from this code. The text assignment is done in the only way possible. I'm not sure what your question is regarding this.

> Second, this in the program's frame of reference refers to the form on
>   which these controls lay, not the controls themselves; How do I refer
>   uniformly to "the control that just got entered" in a way that allows
>   me to have just the one function for all entries, without having to
>   make different ones for each control?

`sender` is always the object from which the event was raised in the `EventHandler` delegate: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx)

Comment: Regarding `AccessibleDescription`, I figured it would work for my purposes-- it's an attribute that holds a string. `Text` would also work, except that in `textboxes`, this... actually displays as the text. What I am trying to find is just a "description" attribute that lets me lay in a string that I can later inject into the `statusStrip`. I was just confirming that `AccessibleDescription` is an attribute that can do that, and that it follows good coding practices to do so.

Comment: And regarding `sender`, from what I understood by your saying, rather than type `this.AccessibleDescription`, I should be typing `sender.AccessibleDescription`, however that isn't an attribute of `sender` and doesn't work the way I'm thinking. Perhaps my further misunderstanding clears enough of the way for you to fill in that gap?

Comment: `sender` is of type `object` in `EventHandler`, you'll need to cast it to your actual type to access properties that aren't a part of `object`. If you're trying to to say, pull the text from a text box with the event handler tied to it you'd do something like `toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text`.

Comment: I am sure your answers are comprehensive and accurate-- however, I fear that I am unable to comprehend. My knowledge of the language and the IDE are both too radically basic; I'm so unaccustomed to visual IDEs. I think I'll just have to find some tutorials and try to learn thoroughly before I proceed.